# Венец и корона.

Tags: этимология, синонимы

Существует слово венец, хотелось бы побольше узнать о нём, в том числе и о происхождении. У самого такие мысли: нечто возвышенное, находящееся вверху, а так же законченный цикл, так как слово «венец» применяется при  строительстве срубов и обозначает ряд брёвен. Здесь же хотелось бы узнать и о происхождении слова корона, ввиду его родственной связи с венцом.

Comment: @Сашка-дурак, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ВЕНЕЦ

Др.-рус. веньцъ, о.-с. venьcъ, и.-е. корень ven со значением "вить". Поэтому венец, венок и веник - однокоренные слова.

КОРОНА

Корона - от (лат.) corona - венок. Заимствовано в 16 веке через польский язык.

У греков венец-корона символизировал  духовность и круг как образ вечного движения жизненных сил. У римлян в республиканский период венок стал знаком исключительно воинской доблести, а во времена империи - символом божественности абсолютной императорской власти.

Comment: Хороший ответ! Отсюда, видимо, и "спираль власти", поскольку спираль состоит из витков...

Comment: В латинском языке есть глагол cerno  - разделяю, и.-е. корень (s)ker - разрезать, разделять. В русском языке много слов с этим корнем: кроить, край, корнать, скорняк, кора, куртка, курносый. Если край - это отрезок, граница, то corona (лат.) - это тоже край, венец, верхушка.

Answer (score 1):

"Венец", "венок", как и "корона", означает "нечто свитое". Только "венец" - у славян, а "корона" - у римлян.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Интересно, есть в латинском языке глагол от  corona, наподобе русского "свить"?

Comment: Есть  в  значении  "венчать".  Если  от  "corona".